# ouput php code as plain text from a file

Tags: php, html

Assume we have a `template.php` file with a bunch of html and a bit of php code, for example:

```
...
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <?php echo $content; ?>
    </div>
</body>
...
```

I want to read contents of the file as text (including php code) and output in a textarea for user to be able to edit the template.
I'm trying to accomplish this using `file_get_contents` and render it using `htmlspecialchars`, but it seems to execute the php code upon reading it from the file. How to avoid interpretation and execution of php code in this situation? Googling didn't help, maybe I'm not trying hard enough. Any tips? Thanks!

EDIT:
Ok, I resolved the issue. The problem was that I was passing URL path to the file to `file_get_contents` instead of its file system path, and apparently this caused all the php code to be stripped and ignored (?). Thanks for tips though

Comment: `file_get_contents` wont execute the code, can you show us your approach?

Comment: Can you show your code to generate `$content`

Comment: Can you show us the code where it gets output?

Answer (score 1):

`file_get_contents` will not execute PHP code, unless you're trying to edit a file on a remote server, supplying a URL. In that case, what you get from the remote server will be the executed PHP code, not the source.

Either edit a local file, or you will need to supply a "backdoor" that will send you back the code of a given PHP file. Be careful, for this is a security breach - anyone might read the source code of your PHP.

A way to avoid this is to only accept to supply files if they are in a given directory. 
Another might be check the file contents:

```
<?php

    // This file will read any local PHP file (or any file of any kind,
    // returning it as text), provided they contain a written agreement
    // to be read.
    if (!isset($_REQUEST['file']))
        die("ERROR: no file supplied");
    $path = $_REQUEST['file'];
    if (!is_readable($path))
        die("ERROR: file is not readable");
    $content = file_get_contents($path);
    if (false === strpos($content, "IT IS OK TO READ THIS FILE AS SOURCE"))
        die("ERROR: this file is not authorized");
    if (false !== strpos($content, "IT IS NOT OK TO READ THIS FILE AS SOURCE"))
        die("ERROR: this file is not authorized");
    Header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    Header("Content-Length: " . strlen($content));
    die($content);
?>
```

To be able to read the file, the file itself must contain a declaration such as

```
// IT IS OK TO READ THIS FILE AS SOURCE
```

and must also *not* contain a declaration of opposite meaning.